# Build issue in my STM32-NUCLEO project using the Eclipse IDE

Tags: cmake, build, stm32, eclipse-cdt, nucleo

I am reading Mastering STM32 by Carmine Noviello and got to the chapter where I am about to work on the hello-nucelo project. I followed everything to the letter and still got the following error (see attachment):

```
23:33:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project hello-nucleo ****
make all 
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo "Building file: ../system/src/stm32f7-hal/stm32f7xx_hal.c", ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier sp�cifi� est introuvable.
make: *** [system/src/stm32f7-hal/subdir.mk:57: system/src/stm32f7-hal/stm32f7xx_hal.o] Error 2
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

23:33:26 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 522ms)
```

[image: error screenshot]

What can be the problem in this case?

I tried playing around with the settings and tool chain editor tabs based on things I have seen online but nothing worked.